# d2i_X509_CRL_bio returns NULL, error number 0xd06b08e

Tags: openssl, asn.1

Below is my code where i m fetching crl using http

```
bp_bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(http_reply->payload, -1);
if(!bp_bio) {
    printf("recieved no data in http reply");
}

crl = d2i_X509_CRL_bio(bp_bio, NULL);
if (!crl) {
    while ((l=ERR_get_error_line_data(&file,&line,&data,&flags)) != 0) {
        printf( "\n: CRL Error %x : %s : %s : %d\n",
                l, ERR_error_string(l,buf), file,line);
    }
    printf( "parsing failed");
} else {
    ret = X509_CRL_dup(crl);
}
BIO_free(bp);
```

Error i am getting is:

> CRL Error d06b08e : error:0D06B08E:lib(13):func(107):reason(142) :
>   a_d2i_fp.c : 246

Why is d2i_X509_CRL_bio returning NULL, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `openssl errstr 0xd06b08e` returns `error:0D06B08E:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_read_bio:not enough data`. It looks like `http_reply->payload` is too small or an incomplete read. Can you provide the CRL's data?

Comment: i m downloading crl from  http://ss.symcb.com/ss.crl. 
and data size in (int)http_reply->bytes is 1163154

Answer (score 1):

> Error i am getting is:
>
> ```
> CRL Error d06b08e : error:0D06B08E:lib(13):func(107):reason(142) : a_d2i_fp.c : 246
> ```
>
> Why is d2i_X509_CRL_bio returning NULL, and how do I fix it?

The problem is below. `http_reply->payload` is binary data with embedded NULLs, so you need to provide an explicit length, and not use `-1`.

```
bp_bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(http_reply->payload, -1);
```

I'm guessing if you change -1 to 1163154, then it will work as expected:

```
$ ls -al ss.crl 
-rw-r--r--  ...  1163154 Nov 17 04:06 ss.crl
```

Also see the [`bio_new_mem_buf`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/BIO_new_mem_buf.html) man page:

> BIO_new_mem_buf() creates a memory BIO using len bytes of data at buf,
>   if len is -1 then the buf is assumed to be nul terminated and its
>   length is determined by strlen. The BIO is set to a read only state
>   and as a result cannot be written to...

---

Here's how you can verify OpenSSL's side of things.

***Fetch CRL***

```
$ wget -O ss.crl 'http://ss.symcb.com/ss.crl'
--2016-11-17 07:15:49--  http://ss.symcb.com/ss.crl
Resolving ss.symcb.com (ss.symcb.com)... 23.4.181.163 ...
Connecting to ss.symcb.com (ss.symcb.com)|23.4.181.163|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/pkix-crl]
Saving to: ‘ss.crl’

ss.crl                  [  <=>               ]   1.11M  3.75MB/s    in 0.3s
```

***Verify CRL***

Use Peter Gutmann's [dumpasn1](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/) to see if its well formed:

```
$ dumpasn1 ss.crl 
      0 1163149: SEQUENCE {
      5 1162868:   SEQUENCE {
     10       1:     INTEGER 1
     13      13:     SEQUENCE {
     15       9:       OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               :         sha256WithRSAEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 11)
     26       0:       NULL
               :       }
     28     126:     SEQUENCE {
     30      11:       SET {
     32       9:         SEQUENCE {
     34       3:           OBJECT IDENTIFIER countryName (2 5 4 6)
     39       2:           PrintableString 'US'
               :           }
               :         }
     43      29:       SET {
     45      27:         SEQUENCE {
     47       3:           OBJECT IDENTIFIER organizationName (2 5 4 10)
     52      20:           PrintableString 'Symantec Corporation'
               :           }
               :         }
     74      31:       SET {
     76      29:         SEQUENCE {
     78       3:           OBJECT IDENTIFIER organizationalUnitName (2 5 4 11)
     83      22:           PrintableString 'Symantec Trust Network'
               :           }
               :         }
    ...
1162878      13:   SEQUENCE {
1162880       9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER
               :       sha256WithRSAEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 11)
1162891       0:     NULL
               :     }
1162893     257:   BIT STRING
               :     A6 4F 77 4E 4C EB E2 6A 13 28 02 25 6C D8 41 56
               :     71 35 19 02 47 53 44 B0 F1 6A CB 37 61 EC 1F 20
               :     56 08 97 0C 58 33 7F 40 7E 87 29 0B 47 35 28 8B
               :     1B 2A 0D 1F C5 1F F8 03 E8 6A FF E7 D3 BF C3 69
               :     8D 3D BF 8D 1A 44 4A A2 2A 5A C3 1C 8E 5F 0C 1F
               :     24 3E 49 99 8E F3 98 CB BD 3C EA D4 A0 A2 3C E6
               :     D9 10 FE F2 C0 27 97 75 25 58 27 84 F0 1B 90 A3
               :     0D 55 D7 EA D3 AE 0C BC BB F3 D7 77 CD 3A 0D 19
               :             [ Another 128 bytes skipped ]
               :   }

0 warnings, 0 errors.
```

***Load CRL***

```c
$ cat test-crl.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  BIO* bio = BIO_new_file("ss.crl", "r");
  if(bio == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create BIO\n");
      exit(1);
    }

  X509_CRL* crl = d2i_X509_CRL_bio(bio, NULL);
  if(crl == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create CRL\n");
      exit(1);
    }

  fprintf(stdout, "Loaded CRL\n");

  X509_CRL_free(crl);
  BIO_free(bio);

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -I /usr/local/include test-crl.c /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a -o test-crl.exe

$ ./test-crl.exe 
Loaded CRL
```

---

You can usually make sense of the error codes with the `openssl errstr` utility:

```
$ openssl errstr 0xd06b08e
error:0D06B08E:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_read_bio:not enough data
```

The only time I have seen it fail is when decoding FIPS error codes *if* the `openssl` utility is not configured for FIPS.

---

***http_reply->payload***

You should verify your `http_reply->payload` is the same data provided by other tools, like `wget`. Below shows the first and last 64 bytes when fetching with `wget`.

```
$ wget -O ss.crl 'http://ss.symcb.com/ss.crl'
--2016-11-17 14:12:20--  http://ss.symcb.com/ss.crl
Resolving ss.symcb.com (ss.symcb.com)... 23.4.181.163 ...
Connecting to ss.symcb.com (ss.symcb.com)|23.4.181.163|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/pkix-crl]
Saving to: ‘ss.crl’
...

$ head -c 64 ss.crl | xxd -g 1
0000000: 30 83 11 bf 8d 30 83 11 be 74 02 01 01 30 0d 06  0....0...t...0..
0000010: 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 0b 05 00 30 7e 31 0b  .*.H........0~1.
0000020: 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 55 53 31 1d 30 1b 06  0...U....US1.0..
0000030: 03 55 04 0a 13 14 53 79 6d 61 6e 74 65 63 20 43  .U....Symantec C

$ tail -c 64 ss.crl | xxd -g 1
0000000: 16 2a d7 ab 7c e2 42 0e 95 32 14 fe f1 0d b8 6d  .*..|.B..2.....m
0000010: a4 9b ec 17 fb b3 db d2 0b 9d 83 a8 a7 79 5b d5  .............y[.
0000020: e9 56 4d aa 65 e3 3b f5 ad 79 58 c7 0a d4 00 3b  .VM.e.;..yX....;
0000030: f8 c6 73 df 9e c0 54 7d 57 05 2d 7f cb 5c bc 74  ..s...T}W.-..\.t
```

Comment: It is still failing after providing exact value

Comment: @user3050267 - ***if*** its the same error, then it sounds like the code that populates `http_reply->payload` is not working as expected. Have you verified the size of `payload` is the expected size when using other tools like `wget`? Have you saved `http_reply->payload` to a file and then verified it with `dumpasn1` or run it through the program above?

Comment: CRL Error d09e09b : error:0D09E09B:lib(13):func(158):reason(155) : x_name.c : 203 CRL Error d08303a : error:0D08303A:lib(13):func(131):reason(58) : tasn_dec.c : 697

Comment: @user3050267 - fix the code that populates `http_reply->payload`.

Comment: if mime type is application/pkix-crl we should convert to pkcs7?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in openssl 1.0.2h where we are unable to download crl more than 1 mb 
X509_NAME_MAX too small for CRL processing
https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-dev/2016-May/006815.html